# MPAndroidChart Android method setDrawVerticalGrid/setGridColor not found

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

So long story short, I used [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) it works great(thanks to creators). As there were couple of crashes in this lib, we decided to update the library to latest.

After updating to latest versions of Library lots of methods/classes started showing error(not found). Some examples are

```
chart.setGridColor(Color.WHITE & 0xAAFFFFFF);
YLabel y = chart.getY..... // Seems this is changed to YAxis

chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false) // Error not found
chart.setTypeFace //
```

There are other errors as well, tried alot but seems no links to point out which latest api to be followed.

Generally when Google removes some apis, they mention which one to use instead of this one.

P.S:- I hope this gets answer by Mr Philip Jahoda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chart.drawVerticalGrid(...)` also moved to the axis. `YAxis` now controls the horizontal grid via `yAxis.setDrawGridLines(...)`, `XAxis` controls the vertical grid via the same method.

For more information I suggest you check out the [examples](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample) which are always up to date with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for asking this, is there any doc where one can see links between older apis and latest one?

Comment: No, der are no docs where you can see the difference. But you can always find the latest docs [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki).